# Xcode 7.1 with GCC

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

I am having trouble in the terminal prompt for $ gcc since i downloaded Xcode 7.1.

$ xcode-select --install Message:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

GCC Message: 
     clang: error: no input files

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says it all: no input files.

Comment: Well. Thank you very much